# How to find out where the Fang and Bone is?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I spoke with Kilton on the western eye island of the Skull Lake. Later I was actively looking for him and I teleported to Hateno, and found him where he's said to be, according to [this seemingly complete guide](https://www.polygon.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-guide-walkthrough/2017/6/22/15854540/fang-and-bone-location-kilton-mon-monster-parts-dark-set-medals-of-honor).

Now I want to find the store again so I stalked his Hateno spot for 20 nights by sleeping in my home until morning, then until noon, then until night, then at night go to his spot and back to my home. But it didn't work.

Another guide on the Internet mentioned there'd be a sign if he'd appear at one spot at night. So I tried all of other locations, in a single in-game day to find that sign or the shop. But there was nothing.

I thought maybe I loaded a previous save where I haven't spoken to Kilton or started the quest, but no: everything is fine on that level.

So how can I find the Fang and Bone reliably?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Fang and Bone appears outside every major settlement between 9pm and 5am (except Goron City) in the same spot every night.

It's fairly easy to locate, simply by finding a vantage point and scanning the surrounding area.

> The exact locations of the Fang and Bone are as follows:
>
> - underneath the bridge to Tarrey Town in Lake Akkala in the Akkala Highlands
> - west of the Ancient Furnace in Hateno Village in East Necluda, on Korne Beach in East Necluda
> - among some ruins west of Gerudo Town in the West Barrens in the Gerudo Desert
> - south of the Hebra Trailhead Lodge in the Hebra Mountains
> - southeast of the Veiled Falls in the Lanayru Great Spring
> - above Lantern Lake in West Necluda.

[Source](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Fang_and_Bone)

It is important to note that he will only appear when you show up in an area *after* the time that he is meant to show up. He will not simply materialize in front of you when the clock strikes 2100. Your best bet is to wait until 2130-2200, and approach the area/teleport to the location then, but you can re-teleport to the same spot to re-load the area (I have personally tested this).

Alternatively, people have suggested locating him under the Bridge near Tarrey Town, which seems to "reset" his cycle.

Comment: Does it show up at each town, every night?

Comment: It will show up outside the town that you arrive at within the time frame.

Comment: Well, then I definitively have a bug as it doesn't show up at all, despite having talked to Kilton...

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire are you sure he's moved? Double check back at Skull Lake and see if he's still there

Comment: I just checked again, both at night and during the day, and Kilton isn't on its left-eye island of Skull Lake. I created a new game in that new game, I could speak to him and visit him at night afterwards in two different cities, several times. So it works. My original game must be corrupted or something like that. I'll accept the answer, because me having a bug shouldn't mean the info is incorrect. The answer is correct.

Answer (score -3):

I think he'll only show up once you've got Mon extract from one of the traveller you saved

Comment: If you're not sure whether your answer is true, you shouldn't post it. Indeed, this answer is completely false.