# Does Bozai show up before defeating Vah Naboris?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

[Bozai](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Bozai) is the NPC in BOTW that gives the player snow and sand boots. I am searching for him around the outskirts of Gerudo Town and I can not find him. I have also looked at the tent he would sit in. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/a3gm3d/anyone_knows_what_triggers_bozai_showing_up_in/) has a comment saying he can appear before completing the Vah Naboris dungeon, I however still do not see him. Not sure if this matters, but I have not talked to Impa (thus not completing the Seek Out Impa quest).

Does anyone know if it is required for me to defeat Vah Naboris before Bozai appears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the information provided in the wiki, it might be a time-related thing (emphasis mine):

> Link can first find Bozai **sometimes** running around the Gerudo Desert in front of Gerudo Town.

This would imply perhaps a time relevant thing. I can definitely say that it is *not* related to Vah Naboris, however. [Another post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/a3gm3d/anyone_knows_what_triggers_bozai_showing_up_in/) has been able to provide this as well:

> You definitely don't have to do Vah Naboris. Just recently I was heading towards the Rito Village and surrounding area, but decided to quickly get the Snow Boots for ease of travel. Headed straight there and found him running around like usual. Nothing special done.

There is a suggestion that it *might* be bugged, but it could also simply be related to other side quests, or simply be time related. If it *is* tied to any other quests, the only one I can think of is potentially getting the Gerudo Set from the [Forbidden City Entry](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Forbidden_City_Entry) quest, and potentially meeting Riju.

Otherwise, try to simply re-load the area (fast travel away, then back again) to see if it resolves the problem, otherwise, it might be bugged; at which point [restarting the game would be the only way to fix it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348432/how-to-find-out-where-the-fang-and-bone-is/348433#comment490883_348433), but it is not essential.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer by VividVirtue](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75608332?page=2) states that they were able to have Bozai spawn after speaking with Purah and receiving the camera rune. This actually makes a lot of sense because I recall speaking with the three NPCs at Serene Stable that give the Leviathan Bones side quest, however, their dialogue never triggered the quest because I do not have the camera rune. I assume this is true for all quests relating to the camera rune.

I wish it was stated in the wiki about Bozai that you need the camera rune to have him spawn.

Comment: That makes so much sense!

Answer (score 2):

According to the wiki:

> After the completion of "The Eighth Heroine", Bozai can be found at a tent outside of the front of Gerudo Town.

Remember that you need to look like a girl to be able to talk with him, you will do the trick with the **gerudo set**.

This is essential since Bonzai plays an important role for the completion of the quest:

Be sure you are wearing the Gerudo Clothes and run counter-clockwise around Gerudo Town. You will run into a man named Bozai. Talk to him while wearing the Gerudo clothes and he will start talking to Link. After hearing that Link is interested in his Sand Boots, he will set Link off on a quest to find the Eighth Heroine, beginning the side quest.

> Link can explore Gerudo Town in search of a clue about the Eighth Heroine. If he visits Patricia, the sand-seal of the Gerudo Chief Riju, he can feed her some Wildberries. Through Padda, who can translate Particia's words, Link learns that "Risoka Snowfield rests upon the shoulders of the eighth heroine..." Risoka Snowfield is a marked location on the map at the west end of the Gerudo Highlands. The Statue of the Eighth Heroine is located just to the north, in the valley that leads down to the Hemaar's Descent.

The fastest way to reach the area is to warp to the Kema Kosassa Shrine at the Risoka Snowfield. Alternatively, travel to the west end of the Tanagar Canyon and from there you can climb up Hemaar's Descent. Once you draw near to the statue, it becomes an actual discoverable location on the map. Take a picture of the upper portion of the statue, so the head is in the photograph.

Return to Gerudo Town and once again put on the Gerudo Clothes. **Find Bozai** running around Gerudo Town and show him the picture. As a thanks for finding the picture, he will give Link the Sand Boots. However, he will take back his snow boots.

After completing The Eighth Heroine, Link can speak with Bozai once again and begin `The Forgotten Sword` side quest.

So, you **don't need** to complete the Vah Naboris dungeon for that.

Answer (score 1):

hi You definitely don't have to do Vah Naboris. Just recently I was heading towards the Rito Village and surrounding area but decided to quickly get the Snow Boots for ease of travel. Headed straight there and found him running around like usual. Nothing special done.

Answer (score 0):

Bozai will show up after you meet Riju, leave the city, and come back. I assume you also have to have the camera rune already; I haven't tried without it.

I had this problem - I had the camera rune and the Gerudo outfit, but Bozai was nowhere to be seen. After reading these answers, I went into the palace in Gerudo Town, triggered the cutscene, got my quest updated, and checked for Bozai. No dice. But when I warped away to a tower and then came back to the shrine outside Gerudo Town, there he was, running in circles and panicking.